# Form (HTML) to MySQL Database via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my code for the HTML form.

```
<html>
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
<h3>Category:</h3>
<input type="text" name="post_category">
<h3>Post title:</h3>
<input type="text" name="post_title">
<h3>Post tags (a,b,c...):</h3>
<input type="text" name="post_tags">
<h3>Post (half):</h3>
<input type="text" name="post_half">
<h3>Post (score):</h3>
<input type="text" name="post_score">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

I have the databse set up but how do i connect these things onto the database?

So when you click submit, the data goes to the database.

Comment: Check the $_POST global variable and the connection classes, maybe PDO to your database brand in php's world.

Answer (score 2):

When your form is submitted, the data will be sent to the file send_post.php using the HTTP POST method. You can find the submitted form data in the global variable $_POST.

This guide will help you with how to save the data in a database: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp